# Dark lines flickering between vertically aligned designs on the ground - but only some of them

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I recently made a few designs in ACNL to serve as roads for my town. Everything looks okay when I put them down, except for one thing.

[image: GAH STOP THE FLICKERING MY EYES AHAHAAHDFHFHAHGHSH]

Dark lines are flickering in the vertical space between designs that both contain the "edge" of the road. Why is this, and is there any way to fix it? Does it have to do with the number of colors used in the designs, perhaps?

**EDIT:**

I messed around a bit, and I think I have identified the issue. The designs/textures seem to not actually fill all of the space they're taking up on the ground, but are instead tiled upward for a fraction of a pixel. This means that all of the designs with the dark row at the bottom of them tile upwards ever so slightly and therefore show a bit of the bottom row of pixels at the top.

Here's a comparison between the original textures and one where I've dotted the bottom row:

[image: Blargh so terrible]
[image: BLARGH SO EVEN MORE TERRIBLE]

I suppose my question still stands - is there any way to fix this problem without making my designs look terrible?

**EDIT 2:**

The lines flicker as the camera moves, and are as such dependent on where the camera is. Once the camera stops moving, the lines stay in whatever state they were in. From some angles, they are not visible at all. These lines appear regardless of color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue on how the 3ds handles texture sampling. I tried to shift it in many ways including shifting up the dark color and putting a gray in between so it'd look better but it still looked bad. for the most part people usually have patterns without edges.

I suggest making the edges's colours lighter and the path colours dark so that this effect will fade away a bit. (since your path's use a dark brown to border the edges you should lighten and gray it)

Comment: So far I have only encountered any of sort of similar issue with Animal Crossing - then again, it is the only 3DS game I know of that let's you supply your own textures. These edges do not appear when you tile your design in your house, and is more well-defined depending on where the camera is situated. I have so far moved the "edge" in a pixel, but it looks strange and this is certainly not a limitation Nintendo meant to establish.

Comment: There is a chance that it might have something to do with the fact that outside the 3d world has that scrolling affect the further north an object is from you and inside buildings this doesn't happen.

Comment: The texture bending might have something to do with it - changing camera angle in a house with designs in its still does not provoke this issue.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for the time being, since it really seems to be a bug I can't do anything about. Think you can elaborate on why the 3DS' texture sampling messes this up, or aren't you into the details? Oh, and the whole "dark path, light edges" thing is quite hopeless - you'd get the same problem, except with light lines instead of dark.

Comment: unfortunately no, unless someone who's worked with the software and hardware from Nintendo came here to explain the specifics I think this is as close to an explanation as we can get for the time being.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt I'd get much answer from Nintendo themselves. Thanks for helping me make sure it's an error with ACNL or the 3DS, and not just my copy, though!

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible this feature is by design so that tiled patterns don't have separations due to the curvature of the ground. In such case, you're stuck with it, and all you can really do is change it.

Comment: It is possible, sure. What I didn't mention originally in the question (and in retrospect should have) is that the "flickering" I mentioned is dependent on where the camera is. As the camera moves, the edge flickers, and once the camera stops the edges stay in whatever state they are in.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with your screen. Sometimes lines of different colors will flash on screens, for me it's a blue line when I play Petz Dogs 2. If not it may be a glitch or a bug.

Comment: Since the effect appears in screenshots, it's not a screen problem.

Comment: @Toomai Not necessarily, while the screen shot takes a picture its taking a picture of what the computer gives it. So if the screen is showing a picture of a black line the image will show the black line.

Comment: @YoungGuilo That's not a screen problem, though. It's a problem with the graphics controller, then.